# How to install gensim from anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, anaconda, conda

When I put the following command in anaconda prompt

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim
```

Python stops working and shows the following error message:

[image]

How do I deal with this problem?

Comment: If you have an issue with Gensim, then writte it here: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues . Did you try 1) "conda update conda" then 2) "conda install gensim" ?

Answer (score 5):

As per the documentation https://anaconda.org/anaconda/gensim

install it by

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim
```

It might take a while to solving the environment

Comment: I get the message `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.` but the "flexible slve" also doesn't work.

Comment: Same issue as Adam_G for me. Attempting to install from any channel (including the recommended `-c anaconda` fails with the same error: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gensim`

Answer (score 4):

I usually in stall `gensim` using `pip` on anaconda prompt using the following command

```
pip install -U gensim
```

or simply

```
pip install gensim
```

as shown in the [`anaconda documentation`](https://pypi.org/project/gensim/).

Comment: I already install `pip install -U gensim` in anaconda prompt and success. But when I try to `import gensim` to jupyter notebook then `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'`

Comment: @DilaAzuri Could you confirm that you installed it in the same environment that you are currently running your jupyter notebook. You can quickly check this by running `!pip install gensim` to see if you get `Requirement already satisfied: gensim in ...` message.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is for Windows 10, Anaconda. Where I want to use gensim with Spyder.

**Solution:** Use Anaconda Navigator, and install package from there: Open Anaconda Navigator -> Environments (base) -> not installed (packages) -> (search for) gensim -> check the gensim option from the drop down list-> Press apply button -> (wait for a while, it will search other dependencies, then press the button one more time to install required package)

[Scree shot of Anaconda Navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxrix.png)

**History:** On anaconda command prompt, using conda command, I installed gensim. Every thing looks perfect but it was even not imported, "import gensim", in command prompt.

**Bonus:** Same is true for tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the conda-forge channel. Try running

```
conda install -c conda-forge gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your command on Windows with conda version 4.4.10, and it installed with success.

Try to updating to the latest version, as suggested in the comments.
Also if that doesn't work (it happened to me with other modules), try from the Anaconda prompt: `pip install -U gensim`.For me it worked for other occasions.

And the last solution is to download the archive version and build it yourself locally.